# How to write an atomic function in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, atomic

I'm programming in Java. I have a pool of jobs (`BlockingQueue`), and some threads will monitor this pool.  When there is a new job, threads will try to take this job. The job performs some tasks, so I don't want the operating system to take the CPU for other threads when this job has not finished. This means I want my job as an atomic job.

Comment: Writing in java and want to take control of CPU. The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think this is possible. You cannot change OS level CPU scheduling from Java code. Best you can do ia give high priority to your thread. But step back a minute. What do you want by making it ATOMIC? Java provides synchronization to make sure another thread will not enter a certain code block while one thread is in it.

Comment: Dear Sammer,
I got your idea. I wil try to use synchronization to fix this issue. Thanks so much!